# How to convert Painter to Bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
fun BlurImage(
    painter: Painter,
) {
    val bitmap = painter.asBitmap(); // how do I convert Painter into Bitmap?
    val blurredBitmap = RenderScriptToolkit.blur(bitmap, 24)

    // ...
}

BlurImage(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.sample_image))
```

I'm trying to simplify my code, hence I would like to pass Painter as the argument into `BlurImage()`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You're already passing a `Painter` to `BlurImage`. Please could you clarify your question?

Comment: Yes I am, perhaps there's some confusion. The problem lies at I'm unable to convert `Painter` into `Bitmap`, thus `RenderScriptToolkit.blur()` is getting a compile error